# Implement multiple receivers to read from a multiple partitions in a topic with Reactor Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactor-kafka

I have 1000 partitions in a topic. I want to have one thread reading from one partition in a topic, transform the message and write to another topic. I am adding multithreading for better throughput. I am trying to achieve this using reactor-Kafka - https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/1.3.5-SNAPSHOT/reference/index.html#_introduction
My understanding is in reactor, each receiver gets its own single-threaded scheduler, so I would have to create 1000 receivers to achieve the above mentioned scenario. I have been looking for examples for this but I couldn't find any and I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

This is the code I have that reads from all partition in a topic, transforms the message and write to another topic.

```
static class ReactiveTransposeAndSend extends SetKafkaProperties {

    SenderOptions<Integer, String> senderOptions =
        SenderOptions.<Integer, String>create(producerProps)
            .maxInFlight(1024);

    KafkaSender<Integer, String> sender = KafkaSender.create(senderOptions);

    ReceiverOptions<Integer, String> receiverOptions =
        ReceiverOptions.<Integer, String>create(consumerProps)
            .subscription(Collections.singleton(SOURCE_TOPIC));


    ReactiveTransposeAndSend(Map<String, Object> consumerPropsOverride, Map<String, Object> producerPropsOverride, String bootstrapServers, String sourceTopic, String destTopic) {
        super(consumerPropsOverride, producerPropsOverride, bootstrapServers, sourceTopic, destTopic);
    }

    public Disposable ReadProcessWriteRecords() {
        Scheduler writerScheduler = Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(60, 60, "writerThreads");
        Scheduler readerScheduler = Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(60, 60, "readerThreads");
        return KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions)
            .receive()
            .doOnNext( r -> System.out.printf("Record received: " + r.value() + " in thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + System.lineSeparator()))
            .map(m -> SenderRecord.create(processRecord(m),m.receiverOffset()))
            .as(sender::send)
            .doOnNext(m->m.correlationMetadata().acknowledge())
            .doOnError(e -> e.printStackTrace())
            .subscribe();
    }

    private ProducerRecord<Integer, String> processRecord( ReceiverRecord<Integer, String> message) {
        System.out.printf( "Processing record " + message.value() + " in thread: "
            + Thread.currentThread().getName() + System.lineSeparator()) ;
        return new ProducerRecord<Integer,String>(DESTINATION_TOPIC, message.key(), message.value()+ " updated");
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could give me suggestions or point me to examples to have multiple receivers consume messages from multiple partitions.

Updated Code:

```
static class ReactiveConsumeTransposeAndSend extends SetKafkaProperties {

    SenderOptions<Integer, String> senderOptions =
        SenderOptions.<Integer, String>create(producerProps)
            .maxInFlight(1024);

    KafkaSender<Integer, String> sender = KafkaSender.create(senderOptions);

    ReceiverOptions<Integer, String> receiverOptions =
        ReceiverOptions.<Integer, String>create(consumerProps)
            .subscription(Collections.singleton(SOURCE_TOPIC))
        .addAssignListener(partitions -> {
        System.out.printf("Partitions assigned" + partitions + System.lineSeparator());})
        .addRevokeListener(partitions -> {
            System.out.printf("Partitions assigned" + partitions + System.lineSeparator());})
        ;


    ReactiveConsumeTransposeAndSend(Map<String, Object> consumerPropsOverride, Map<String, Object> producerPropsOverride, String bootstrapServers, String sourceTopic, String destTopic) {
        super(consumerPropsOverride, producerPropsOverride, bootstrapServers, sourceTopic, destTopic);
    }

    public Disposable ReadProcessWriteRecords() {
        Scheduler writerScheduler = Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(60, 60, "writerThreads");
        Scheduler readerScheduler = Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(60, 60, "readerThreads");
        return KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions)
            .receive()
            .doOnNext( r -> System.out.printf("Record received: " + r.value() + " from partition: " + r.partition() + " in thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + System.lineSeparator()))
            .map(m -> SenderRecord.create(processRecord(m),m.receiverOffset()))
            .as(sender::send)
            .doOnNext(m->m.correlationMetadata().acknowledge())
            .doOnError(e -> e.printStackTrace())
            .subscribe();
    }

    private ProducerRecord<Integer, String> processRecord( ReceiverRecord<Integer, String> message) {
        System.out.printf( "Processing record " + message.value() + " in thread: "
            + Thread.currentThread().getName() + System.lineSeparator()) ;
        return new ProducerRecord<Integer,String>(DESTINATION_TOPIC, message.key(), message.value()+ " updated");
    }
}
```

I updated the code following the sample from [SampleConsumer.java](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/blob/main/reactor-kafka-samples/src/main/java/reactor/kafka/samples/SampleConsumer.java), as suggested by @nipuna. However, these are the print statements I receive while running the application:

```
Partitions assigned[metrics-2, metrics-1, metrics-0]
Record received:  A16 from partition: 2 in thread: reactive-kafka-reactive-group-1
Processing record  A16 in thread: reactive-kafka-reactive-group-1
Record received:  B14 from partition: 1 in thread: reactive-kafka-reactive-group-1
Processing record  B14 in thread: reactive-kafka-reactive-group-1
```

So the same thread ("eactive-kafka-reactive-group-1") is being used to consume the messages from the partitions. I want to have different threads consuming messages from different partitions.

Answer (score 0):

As documentation example shows in [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/reference/) under the sub topic `sample consumer` it is consuming from multiple partitions from a topic.

you can see sample consumer code in [SampleConsumer.java](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/blob/main/reactor-kafka-samples/src/main/java/reactor/kafka/samples/SampleConsumer.java).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I updated the code following the sample in the OP

Comment: However, based on the print statements I receive the same thread ("eactive-kafka-reactive-group-1") is being used to consume the messages from the partitions. I want to have different threads consuming messages from different partitions.
I have added the print statements in the post

Comment: If you increase number of threads (maximum with number of partitions) in same consumer group, kafka will divide the partitions to the threads. That means if you have 2 partitions, when you start 2 threads, partition will consumed by both threads. But same partition will not be consumed by both threads at once.

Comment: How do I increase the number of threads in the consumer group. I think that is the point I am not understanding

Comment: Honestly I don't know about Java lot. there should be a way do that in language level. But You can increase number of consumer applications and do the same.